# Test linear regression coeficient significance if the residuals are not normally distributed

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, linear-model, normality-assumption

I have a linear regression with 51 data points, and I would like to get the confidence intervals and to test the coeficient's significance, but the problem is that the residuals are not normally distributed. What should I do?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible things you could do are:

- find a better model by including or excluding covariates;
- compute the distribution of the test statistic by the bootstrap method.

Comment: Thanks for an advice. I would also like to ask how to (and whether I can) get the confidence interval for the predictions of the regression if the residuals are not normally distributed.

Comment: sure, you can use the bootstrap method also for this.

Comment: Is 51 a large enough sample size for bootstrap?

Comment: If so, how small samples should I take fom it for bootstraping?

Comment: Recall that bootstrapping is done with replacement and for $n=51$, there are $51^{51}$ possible ordered samples with replacement. So the possible number of bootstrap samples is quite large. The larger the number of bootstrap samples you take the better it is.